# Can Dev Hub be enabled if we are on Salesforce Classic?

Tags: salesforce-classic, salesforcedx, dev-hub

We have a big, existing org with tons of Visualforce and Apex and we are very, very far from being able to enable Lightning Experience. The question is, can we enable Dev Hub to start experimenting with Salesforce DX BEFORE we move to Lightning Experience? I had assumed there was no dependency between Lightning Experience and Salesforce DX / Dev Hub, until we read this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_intro.htm

Which says: Available in: Lightning Experience

And then this page:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm

Which says: Enable the Dev Hub in your org so you can create and manage scratch orgs from the command line and Lightning Experience.

This makes it sound like we cannot enable the Dev Hub and therefore cannot play around with Salesforce DX until we enable Lightning Experience. Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: I am on salesforce classic and I have dev hub enabled for my production org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access the dev hub on Salesforce classic. It is a platform feature that is not limited to your UI. I have it enabled on a production instance with Classic.

You can find it under Build > Develop > Dev Hub, and it is currently marked as a BETA feature. [It will be GA on Winter 18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_devhub.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any additional information on what difference Classic vs. Lightning Experience makes with Salesforce DX? For instance, why does the Dev Hub intro link (see original question) say "Available in: Lightning Experience"? It is just an error?

Comment: I think it is just misleading. The feature is available for the platform, regardless of the UI. Maybe the intent was to say that it is ALSO available in LEX, and not just in Classic. They really should change this.